# OpenCV - C library is not working in my Ubuntu11.10

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv, error-handling, header

Resently I'm installed Opencv in my machine. Its working in python well(I just checked it by some eg programs). But due to the lack of tutorials in python I decided to move to c. I just run an Hello world program from http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/

while compiling I got the following error

```
hello-world.c:4:16: fatal error: cv.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I'm new in opencv

Qn : Could you please report what may be the problem - and how I run my helloworld program in c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler cannot find your `cv.h` include file.  If you installed from your package manager, it is probably in `/usr/include/opencv/`.  You need to add that your include search path.  If you are compiling from the command line use `-I` to specify additional include directories. It will be something like -

```
gcc -I /usr/include/opencv/ -o helloworld helloworld.c
```

If you are using Eclipse,

- Right click on the project and select properties.
- Select C/C++ General -> Path and Symbols.
- Select Includes tab.
- In Languages list, select 'GNU C' or 'GNU C++' depending on which you are using.
- Press 'Add...' button and add /usr/include/opencv/
- Save and rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show compiler path to cv.h file. The quick way to find it is to do (on Ubuntu):

```
find /usr -name "cv.h"
/usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h
```

Just add this to the compiler:

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include/opencv -o helloworld helloworld.c
```

Since you asking this question your compiler might also have problems linking your program  to opencv libraries. Just do the same thing only for library files:

```
find /usr -iname "libopencv*"
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so
...
```

add this folder the same way and specify libraries you want to use:

```
gcc helloworld.c -I/usr/local/include/opencv -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -o helloworld
```

that should probably compile. There is a also a short cut you can take and instead of all that steps just use the following command

```
gcc helloworld.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -o helloworld
```

that should take care of all the work of locating required files for you and let you focus on the fun coding part.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you just installed the opencv package.
But, as you want to use opencv in your C program, you may also install the package named just like opencv-devel. If you haven't, install it and than use it as @iagreen said.
Best wishes to you.